# Why did Naruto stop using Sage Mode?

Tags: boruto

Recently, in the *Boruto* web series, Naruto is not using Six Path Sage Mode even when both Naruto and Sasuke are losing the fight against Jigen. Previously, Naruto used Sage Mode along with Tailed Beast power even though nobody is teaching Sage Mode in the Hidden Leaf Village.

Why did Naruto stop using Sage Mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: Naruto still has and uses Six Paths and Toad Sage Mode, although he doesn't use much of the abilities it grants, just the mode in general. This was likely because of the nerf that has been assumed to have happened to some of his abilities.**

---

I'm not sure if there is a definitive answer to why it ***appears*** Naruto stopped using Sage Mode in general, so some of the answer will be speculative based off facts given in the series. (and assumptions that *seem true* that have been made by the fandom)

One major thing that has been noticed by quite a bit of the fandom is that Naruto and Sasuke have seemed to be nerfed in Boruto. As explained here, one of the most valid reasons:

> The answer is simple yet unfortunate: in order for the story of Boruto to truly come to be its own story it requires killing off Naruto and Sasuke. They were too powerful by the end of Shippuden to just kill them off as is. They had to be nerfed.
>
> <sup>Taken from Quora page: [Was Naruto and Sasuke nerfed in Boruto?](https://www.quora.com/Was-Naruto-and-Sasuke-nerfed-in-Boruto-Why-didnt-Naruto-use-the-Truth-seeker-Orbs-and-Sasuke-use-Inferno-Control-and-all-the-other-stuff-we-saw-in-Shippuden)</sup>

This is one thing that has been assumed by a good chunk of the fandom, considering there has been tons of abilities that Naruto & Sasuke have yet to use in the Boruto series, (most of them being what makes them so strong) such as Sasuke's [Planetary Devastation](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Chibaku_Tensei) and *Naruto's* [Truth Seeking Orbs.](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Truth-Seeking_Ball)

There has been an absence of a majority of Naruto's abilities as mentioned above, as well as his Sage Mode abilities. One of the reasons it may appear he doesn't use it is because of the nerf of his abilities, making him use the mode but not its abilities.

---

Away from the guesses/speculations/assumptions, there *is* one final answer. Naruto still has and uses Six Paths Sage Mode.

> [image]
>
> (Naruto's eyes whenever in use of Six Paths **Sage Mode,** not Rikudou Senjutsu.

This same eye pattern is found where Naruto was an adult, which was used against both Momoshiki and Kinshiki, as well as when he fought Isshiki alongside Sasuke.

> [image]
>
> The same eye pattern are present where Naruto was using Six Paths Sage Mode as a teen and as an adult.

As for *Toad* Sage Mode, he has been using that as well, but not as frequently as Six Paths Sage Mode, considering which one is stronger.

Naruto was using regular Toad Sage Mode during the [Naruto: Seventh Hokage and the Scarlet Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naruto:_The_Seventh_Hokage_and_the_Scarlet_Spring) short story *on multiple occasions* as well.

> [image: Blockquote]
>
> Naruto using Sage Mode during Boruto.

---

I think the most logical answer would be that Naruto still has access to Toad and Six Paths Sage Mode, although he doesn't fully utilize the abilities they grant, such as Frog Kumite.

Hes been shown on multiple occasions during the Boruto era that he still uses Toad and Six Paths Sage Mode (as shown in the images above).

Comment: I didn't finish Naruto so I don't know if Naruto ever found a way to circumvent it but isn't there a strong aspect of prep/setup for sage mode and nature chakra in general? The rule with nature chakra is that you can't move while you build it lest you turn into a stone toad. Naruto came up with summoning and releasing shadow clones who built up nature chakra during the Pain fight. Assuming he isn't keeping sage mode shadow clones up 24/7 and lugging around a huge scroll and can't stand still in a fight to build sage mode chakra it makes sense he isn't using regular sage mode much

Comment: @Gatchwar (spoilers in this comment) Kurama befriends Naruto during the Fourth Great Ninja War, as well as Naruto mastering his beast's power which gave him access to a new mode. Kurama informed Naruto that the Kurama Chakra Mode can be stacked with Sage Mode, and it almost instantaneously gave him faster access to Nature Energy. As for Six Paths Sage Mode, he is just using chakra he acquired from elsewhere.

Comment: @Gatchwar I can make a chat room if you have any questions, considering this answer is based off of things quite far in the series and I don't want to spoil it